# Keep only duplicated item in a list

Tags: python

I'Ve a list of surfaces and I calculated their area in another list, so I want to keep only duplicated surfaces twice in my original list

```
Surface = [S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8, S9, S10]

S_Area = [35.67, 0.08, 0.08, 39.56, 39.56, 0.08, 9.05, 44.72, 45.36, 45.36]
```

result should be:

```
S = [S4, S9]
```

Thanks.

Comment: what type are the elements inside `Surface` ? strings ?

Comment: So only the items appering twice ? not the ones appearing 3 times ?

Comment: Nothing is duplicated twice. 45.36 (for example) is duplicated once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `list` to hold the valid keys, and a `set` to keep the seen values, then iterate over the pairs and add the values when you don't have already seen the value and its counts is 2

```
names = ["S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", "S9", "S10"]
values = [35.67, 0.08, 0.08, 39.56, 39.56, 0.08, 9.05, 44.72, 45.36, 45.36]

result = []
result_values = set()

for name, value in zip(names, values):
    if value not in result_values and values.count(value) == 2:
        result.append(name)
        result_values.add(value)

print(result)  # ['S4', 'S9']
```

Answer (score 2):

Shortly with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object:

```
from collections import Counter

surfaces = ["S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", "S9", "S10"]
areas = [35.67, 0.08, 0.08, 39.56, 39.56, 0.08, 9.05, 44.72, 45.36, 45.36]

d = dict(zip(areas[::-1], surfaces[::-1]))
res = [d[k] for k, v in Counter(areas).items() if v == 2]
print(res)
```

---

```
['S4', 'S9']
```